# spring for mongodb escaping parameters to avoid SQL injection

Tags: spring, sql-injection, spring-data-mongodb, nosql

I am a new-by using spring with MongoDB.

I am using a Dao pattern which uses MongoOperations object.

As I have a lot of experience with RDBMS and JPA usually we use setParameter which also takes care for escaping and avoiding SQL injection.

I am wondering if there is such a think in spring for MongoDB. I could not find it but I might be missing something. I have to say I am still not sure if there is an SQL injection risk using Mongo.

Also, is there a way to create Named Queries in MongoDB?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something very similar to SQL injection which is **NOSQL injection**.
The special characters are different but the concept is the same :  the user can control/modify/corrupt the request.

> Yet these databases are still potentially vulnerable to injection attacks, even if they aren't using the traditional SQL syntax. Because these NoSQL injection attacks may execute within a procedural language , rather than in the declarative SQL language, the potential impacts are greater than traditional SQL injection

There is a way to verify, [here is an OWASP page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_NoSQL_injection) that would help you to test.

The basic is to verify that your requests correctly escape `' " \ ; { }` and maybe more.

It seems that spring data mongodb correctly escapes those, but I have no idea if it is completely safe.

As for named query, I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27994316/6695569) is correct and they don't exists but you still have a `@Query` annotation if you have a repository.

And because you are using a custom repository doesn't mean you can't use a repository interface too, Spring data allows you to have an implementation of the repostiroy without implementing it, [see here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations).

Answer (score -1):

There is no such thing as SQL injection in Mongo, since Mongo does not use SQL language at all.

There is no concept of named queries in Spring Data MongoDB, instead you use annotate your repository methods with `@Query`:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String>

  @Query(value="{ 'firstname' : ?0 }", fields="{ 'firstname' : 1, 'lastname' : 1}")
  List<Person> findByThePersonsFirstname(String firstname);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your quick answer. I am not using the MongoRepository I am just using my own DAO interface with set of methods that I execute using MongoOperations. I did read that there are some injections like risks in mongo (See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#how-does-mongodb-address-sql-or-query-injection), but I assume that they are taken care of when using Criteria.where(PROPERTY).is(VALUE) - I assume the is method takes care of it. But still I could not find how to do it myself.

Comment: There is no concept of SQL injection but there is a similar notion. If you have a string " my string's " the character ' will break your query if you don't escape it.So this is not true to say that there is no similar concept